# How to force future method to wait until current thread finish?

Tags: apex, batch, future, after-trigger, schedule

I have an apex code which is called from an after trigger. The apex code calls a future method and sometimes the future method runs after the execution of the current thread and sometimes does not.

I want to force the future method to run only when the context of its call ends. So the idea is: when the thread that started the future methods ends, the future methods is allowed to run.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to tell when the future method will run. If you want it to run after your current code is done executing, you have 2 options:

1. Call your future method as the very last step of your execution
2. Create a scheduleable class and schedule it in a couple of minutes, that way you will be sure that your code has enough time to process

Comment: Since @future methods are committed to an execution queue at the end of the current execution context (together with all other changes), is not that a case that future method will be always executed after first context is done completely?